# Registering activeX contols on user side

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, activex, activexobject

I have been searching last 2 hours to figure out a way to implement activeX control . I actually did it by generating a dll file and accessing it via java script and it works fine if I register it using regasm . But how will this happen on user side ? Is there any default way to do it ?

I found that this articles says generate ocx control but that is no longer available in Visual studio 2008 .

Any light on this will help .

Answer (score 0):

If your "activeX control" is a COM control, register it with RegSvr32.exe.  If you want to create an ActiveX control with an ocx extension, you'll probably need to use VS6.0 or earlier.